# How to make Invoke-Command return empty array instead of null when run script block

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I am creating a function and sometimes, it will return a empty array as there is not result. This function may need to run with `Invoke-Command` for some scenario, such as run on a remote PC and etc.

But what i found that, when my function run under `Invoke-Command` with script block, it cannot return empty array, but just `null`.

So I have a try and find that, the `Invoke-Command` seems to not able to return empty array even though I do that explicitly.

For exmaple:

```
> $foo = @()
> $foo.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                          
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                          
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array 

> $foo = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { @() }
> $foo.GetType()
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $foo.GetType()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

> $foo -eq $null
True
```

So how can I return empty array in this scenario? Any mistake here? Or any trick here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just prepend the returning value with comma `,` (array construction operator). Then the return value will not get flattened into `$null`:

```
$foo = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { ,@() }
```

Comment: Can anyone comment on why this is necessary for Invoke-Command but not a typical function return call?

Comment: As I know powershell functions behave the same - the empty array will get flattened on return.